# Facebook like does not show faces

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I know this question has been asked before, but no answer I've found here or elsewhere has resolved my issue.

I would like my Facebook Like-button to show faces of friends who have liked the same page. Now it does not. If I like the page it shows my facebook profile picture but no other.

- I know I have friends who have liked said page. They cannot see my picture either
- I have used the HTML5 implementation of the button with following html: `<div class="fb-like" data-width="300" data-show-faces="true" data-send="true"></div>`
- There is no issue with the height of the container since it can show one face (my own)

The URL of the page to like is not set in the fb-tag since it's a dynamic like-button that's availible on several pages.

See it in action on the right side of this page: http://www.takespace.se/Campaign/Stoppa-slavhandeln-i-Sverige

Comment: After the July 2013 breaking changes all social plugins _require_ the href to be set (to an absolute URL), according to the Facebook roadmap.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've changed it so it includes the href attribute, but still it just shows one of my friends though I know at least four has liked it.

Comment: @DanielHedenström Have you found a fix? Same problem here.

Comment: @Wolf Not really. It seems kind of arbitrary if the faces are shown or not. Some of my friends says it's working now, but I still only see my own face. Perhaps it has to do with the privacy settings of the facebook account or some other strange logic at facebook.